# PHP validation works but not updating my data in database

Tags: php

```
if($valid_fname!=NULL && $valid_lname!=NULL && $valid_email!=NULL && $valid_contact!=NULL
   && $valid_bg!=NULL &&$valid_gender!=NULL && $valid_address!=NULL && $valid_conpwd!=NULL)
{
     // echo "Updating.....";
     $upd="UPDATE registration SET first_name='$valid_fname',last_name='$valid_lname',
           email_id='$valid_email',mobile_no='$valid_contact',blood_group='$valid_bg',
           gender='$valid_gender',address='$valid_address',
           password='$valid_conpwd' WHERE uid=33";

           mysql_query($upd) or die(mysql_error());
           echo "<script>alert('Your details are updated');window.location='view_personal_client.php';</script>";

}
```

Comment: check spelling and/or post the structure of your table

Comment: sorry but its my first time so there may b issue in format.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$upd="UPDATE `registration` SET `first_name`='".$valid_fname."',`last_name`='".$valid_lname."',`email_id`='".$valid_email."',`mobile_no`='".$valid_contact."',`blood_group`='".$valid_bg."',`gender`='".$valid_gender."',`address`='".$valid_address."',`password`='".$valid_conpwd."' WHERE `uid`=33";
```

Comment: i tried it but its not updating.Yes validatons works but only not updating my data. :(